# inheritance for UI in swift project

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class with 5 subclasses. these classes have many views in common. but all of them have a view which is just for them.

I created a view controller with xib file and I added the common views to that xib file (general.xib) 
and for each subclass, I created a specific view for itself.
I don't know about the best practice.
is it good to have a `UIStackView` in `general.xib` for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

UIStackView will arrange all its subclasses equally/ratio according to our specification. If you want them equally align within you super without any scroll, it's a good one.